# Absolute max voltage of Differential Signal

Tags: clock, differential

I am using IDT 85104 Buffer IC for clock distribution in my design. I need to give the clock output of this Buffer to a device @ 156.25 MHz. I have 2 doubts :-

**1.** In the parameter table of 85104, it is given that Absolute max output voltage is 1150 mV (*with a Note - measurement taken from single ended waveform*). **What is the meaning of Absolute max output voltage of a diff signal and the Note??**

**2.** I am providing this clock to an IC which says Max input voltage is 1V. What is the problem I am going to get here!!.

The clock output of 85104 is HCSL 0.7V.

Please tell me if I should provide additional information.

Datasheet of Input Device can be downloaded from here :-

http://www.idt.com/products/interface-connectivity/pci-express-solutions/pci-express-serial-rapidio-bridges/tsi721-rapidio-bridge

Comment: 85104 is LVCOMS to HCSL fanout buffer and output level of HCSL is never 3.3V, please cross check the output voltage levels you are expecting.

Comment: It is 0.7V. By mistake wrote 3.3V.

Comment: I hope your clock input to the 85104 is LVCMOS/LVTTL i.e. VIH is more than 2V and VIL is less than 0.8. Take care of the terminations suggested in the datasheet diagrams. It will do.

Comment: Can you provide the data sheet of the input device?

Comment: Datasheet Link added in post.

Answer (score 1):

That is a very odd datasheet. Normally when we talk about "absolute maximum" ratings, we mean this table from page 4 in the datasheet:

[image]

These are requirements for how you must use the chip to avoid damaging it.

The spec you are referring to is in a table labelled "AC Characteristics". Normally a "characteristic" spec is a promise from the chipmaker about the behavior of the chip, not a requirement for how you should use the chip.

As I read it, they are promising that the output differential voltage will absolutely not exceed 1150 mV. A figure on page 8 tries to clarify what they mean by the spec:

[image]

I can't say how this relates to the requirements for your other chip without seeing the datasheet for the other chip.

Comment: Datasheet Link added in post.